# Accessing files from mounted file system vs local files on web server (production vs dev)

Tags: javascript, django

I have a Django web application that requires accessing audio wav files. I have a file server containing the wav files which is mounted onto my web server which stores my web application files. I then downloaded the files onto my local filesystem so my web application can access it when I'm developing it locally.

My question is about how to access those files from my web application on production versus local. I'm thinking in my Javascript I'd need to have two different configurations that check if my web application is in production or development. If in production, I'd use the path to the mounted file server, and if in development, I'd use the path to the local filesystem on my computer. Does Django or Javascript provide a way of doing that somehow? And is this the right way of approaching getting files from the web application?

The other option I can think of just uploading the wav files along with my web application to the web server so I can access it locally on production and not have to access it from the mounted file system, but I'm not sure how this affects performance and that might cause headaches of having to upload the files every time a recording gets added or removed.

Would that approach be better or would the first approach be better?

Comment: Are you actually loading the content of the .wav files in python code? Or are you just serving them to the client?

Comment: actually loading the content of the .wav files either in javascript (front end) or python (backend) so the user can play the audio file

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is that users can listen to the audio files when they are using your web application. This is mostly not Django specific.

I recommend that your Django project should have a setting, for example `settings.AUDIO_FILES_URL` that points to the place your audio files are served from. It might be convenient to use a context processor to add that setting to your template rendering contexts as AUDIO_FILES_URL, or you can do it explicitly. It's a good convention to include a trailing slash in the variable's value (that's how STATIC_URL is usually used.) Set the value correctly in each settings file, whether test or production.

Then in your HTML template you can build a URL for a particular audio file. You might do something like this:

`<span data-audio-file-url="{{ AUDIO_FILES_URL }}{{ audio_file_path }}">{{ audio_file_description }}</span>`

Finally, your JavaScript code can read the url and create whatever interface you like. Notice that the javascript doesn't need to know whether it's a production system or not. (You could instead avoid javascript and make an HTML5 audio element, if you like.)

In production, Django should only know the base url for the audio files, it should *not* be involved in serving them. Serving them is something you need to configure the web server to do, i.e. Apache, Nginx or whatever you're using. You could even serve the files from a different host - perhaps making your file server also a static file web server.

Also, I think it would be kind to your users to serve .mp3 instead of .wav!

Comment: How are you able to access that Django settings variable from your HTML or Javascript??

Comment: I added urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
to my urls.py but reactjs is treating that variable as a string when I do       <audio src={"{{ MEDIA_ROOT }}" + props.audio}>Recording</audio> in my javascript file

Comment: I also added django.core.context_processors.media to my settings.py TEMPLATES but it still doesn't work